# Do I have to pay VAT charges on a rented car that wasn't insured?

Tags: international-travel, car-rentals

I rented a car and it got a minor scratch while being parked on a street, but the rental car company covered the bill after I provided my credit card. But per their policy, they do not pay for VAT fees right? Now, they're insisting I pay the VAT charges for the damages ($200 USD).

Do I have to pay this? Being a U.S. citizen, can I get reimbursed for this VAT?

Comment: What do the rental company's Terms & Conditions (in the rental agreement) say about responsibility for  damages to the rented vehicle?

Comment: Which country did this happen? The rules are similar between countries but not identical.

Comment: The rental car company covered the bill, or your credit card insurance covered the bill?

Comment: Who are "they" in "their policy"? The rental agency? Your insurance?

Comment: What do you mean by "covered the bill"?  I am beginning to think that this is a scam: the rental company pays to have the car repaired as a VAT-exempt transaction, then presents it to you as a VAT-liable transaction and says that you have to pay the VAT, which they then keep instead of paying to the revenue authority.  That would be illegal.  What country did this happen in?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The whole concept of VAT is that the end user must pay for it.

To avoid VAT being charged multiple times, businesses reclaim VAT they pay, and charge VAT (and collect it and declare it and give it to the government) to whoever they sell the product or service on to. If it’s another business the process repeats (reclaim VAT on purchase, charge it on sale), if it’s a end user they pay for it and that’s it.

The end result is that:

- Each business charges VAT on the resale price and reclaims VAT on their buying price: so in effect, they give the government an amount based on the difference between buying and resale price: that’s the added value which gives its name to the tax
- The final user effectively pays tax on the total final price

The fact that the business reclaims the tax does not mean they don’t have to charge it to their customers, quite the contrary: it’s their obligation to charge this tax and pass it on to the government.

The sale could be exempt of VAT (the rules are complex) if you were non-resident **and** the service is provided outside the EU or the product leaves the EU.

In this case the service was provided inside the EU, so VAT is owed, exactly like hotel nights, restaurant meals, and the original cost of the car rental, etc.

Comment: VAT is a percentage of the amount you pay for something.  The OP paid $0.  The VAT due on $0 is $0!  That said, the OPs statement about the charge being waived after they provided their credit card doesn't make much sense...

Comment: @Doc That's not my understanding (though it is indeed unclear). What I understand is that the rental company paid for the costs of the repairs (i.e. the garage didn't send the invoice to customer directly), and is now going to bill the customer (OP) for this, including VAT, and OP is disputing the fact that he should pay that VAT (he would like to pay only the amount ex-VAT). It's also unclear if $200 is the amount of the VAT (which would make the repairs very expensive for a minor scratch, IMHO), or if it's the total including VAT.

Comment: Garage?  What garage?  OP damaged a rental car. The question is horribly unclear, which currently makes any answers unlikely to cover the facts.

Comment: @Doc the garage that fixed the damages to the rental car

Comment: @Doc While OP's question is unclear, I believe we are in a very classic scenario of: OP rents a car, OP provides a credit card as guarantee, the car is damaged, the rental company sends it to a garage/workshop for fixes, garage/workshop bills rental company, rental company now wants to bill OP for this (and OP's question is just whether he should pay the VAT on this bill or not). "Covered" here means "they paid for it", but does not mean "they won't charge OP". The rental company could probably just have charged OP's credit card, but they apparently communicated with him before doing so.

Comment: @jcaron or the company is saying "you don't have to pay for the repair, but you do have to pay for the VAT," which seems like a scam.

Comment: For example, if they have the car repaired without paying VAT and then collect the VAT only from the client without remitting it to the government.

Answer (score 1):

Which jurisdiction?

[european-union](/questions/tagged/european-union)

> But per their policy, they do not pay for VAT fees right?

Unlikely.

VAT is a **consumer** tax.

For the European Union the general rule is:

- **if** you are a non-resident **and** the taxed goods/service are **directly** exported

  - the the VAT can be refunded

Since the repaired scratched car will remain in the jurisdiction (i.e. cannot be exported), the tax will not be refunded.

> Do I have to pay this?

Yes, since the service was **consumed** within the jurisdiction.

> Being a U.S. citizen, can I get reimbursed for this VAT?

Citizenship plays no role.

Exceptions exists for not-residents **if** the goods were consumed **outside** of the jurisdiction.

For the European Union this means: outside of the EU customs area.

Comment: As you've said, it's an end-user tax which means that the rental company can claim it back as an input credit. It makes no sense that the consumer should be hit with it in a case like this.

Comment: @Doc the rental company can only claim it back if it is a cost of producing their goods or services.  In this case, the payment for the repair to the car is the customer's liability.  It is therefore taxable.

Comment: @phoog The OP states "rental car company covered the bill", which at least by my reading means that the OP didn't actually pay for the repairs.  But as has already been stated elsewhere, the question is vague and confusing as to exactly what happened. The OP has also stated in a now-deleted response that the car was insured, despite the question stating it wasn't.

Comment: @Doc I have read this as: the rental car company paid **for the OP** using his card. The bill from the repair company would include the VAT for their services.

Comment: @Doc indeed "covered the bill" is ambiguous.  But if the car was insured then the insurance should cover the VAT if payable, and nobody should have to pay the VAT if it isn't payable.  I suppose the question is whether the transaction is a consumer transaction because it is the consumer's liability that led to the repair or a business transaction because the company was the party that purchased the repair service.  It is beginning to smell fishy to me.

Answer (score 1):

> I rented a car and it got a minor scratch while being parked on a street, but the rental car company covered the bill after I provided my credit card. But per their policy, they do not pay for VAT fees right? Now, they're insisting I pay the VAT charges for the damages ($200 USD).

It's difficult to understand exactly what happened and you haven't specified a jurisdiction but none of this seems especially relevant to VAT. As a general rule, if you paid something, even an additional fee charged after the fact, then yes, VAT may be collected on it. In the EU, this does apply to car rentals and additional fees associated with it, car maintenance or mechanics, and fuel. In fact, I think the car rental company even has to collect VAT on the handling fees they charge when you incur a fine for a traffic violation.

If an insurer covers some expense then what usually happens is that service provider (e.g. a garage) will charge for the regular price and the insurer will pay or reimburse it, including the VAT. By contrast, if the car rental company waives a fee or paid something then it would be odd for a private person to pay VAT on a bill they didn't pay (I specify “for a private person” because it works a little differently for businesses).

Answer (score 0):

Nope, no VAT.

You damaged a good (car) owned by another party. You made them whole again by paying for the damage inflicted. Making them whole is not a good or a service, so that is not a taxable event in itself.

The car rental company may have gotten a bill for repairs including VAT, but this VAT is deductible from the VAT they themselves charge (that's why it's a Value **Added** Tax). Hence, their monetary damage does not include that VAT.

Comment: But the customer is liable for the damage to the car, not the rental business.

Comment: @phoo: That is why I wrote "you make them (the rental business) whole again".

Comment: The car rental company is just reselling (supposedly with 0 margin) the service they bought. Doing that, they have to charge, collect and remit VAT (and they should bill and invoice the customer for this, of course, otherwise they cannot claim that VAT). The customer is not an insurance company. One may be able to argue it differently, but it will probably take a good dose of aspirin to go through the details, and probably lawyers to convince the rental company (and their accountants) that there shouldn't be any VAT involved. It would also look like a terrible loophole.